# Pandas pd.read_html : NO TABLES FOUND

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get the table from this website https://www.chronicle.com/interactives/tuition-and-fees through using python and pandas pd.read_html() however I keep getting an error saying no tables found. Any ideas on how to fix this because there is clearly a table there. THANKS!

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far? Would be easier to go from there.

Comment: You can also post the part of the HTML you are expecting to extract from the page.

Comment: basically what I tried is pd.read_html("https://www.chronicle.com/interactives/tuition-and-fees") in order to get the table in pandas form from that webpage and I keep getting the No Table found even though there is a table tag.

Comment: You will need to use somthing like BeautifulSoap, Pandas will not be able to parse the website for you. Check the example here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/    If you would save the example html, you could reference as path_to\example.html, or if you downloaded path_to\tuition-and-fees.html. The other option is that you assign the webpage to a variable using soap

Comment: it seems it is js rendered page. You can't use beautifulsoup